# Inner Join Sub consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy haciendo una consulta la cual debe devolver el codigo del cliente, nombre, años y la cantidad vendida. Cuando no realizo el filtro (que me muestre resultados repetidos) no tengo ningun problema esta es la consulta:

```
select c.codigo_cliente, c.nombre, (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')) - to_number(to_char(fecha_nacimiento,'YYYY'))) as edad, sum(precio*cantidad)
from clientes c inner join facturacion f on c.CODIGO_CLIENTE = f.CODIGO_CLIENTE
inner join detalle d on f.NUMERO = d.NUMERO;
```

pero cuando trato de que no muestre los resultados repetidos (agruparlos) utilizo la siguiente consulta la cual me da el error de identificador invalido en el campo CANTIDAD, la consulta que uso y me muestra el error del identificador es la siguiente:

```
select c.codigo_cliente, c.nombre, (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')) - to_number(to_char(fecha_nacimiento,'YYYY'))) as edad, sum(precio*cantidad)
from clientes c inner join facturacion f on c.CODIGO_CLIENTE = f.CODIGO_CLIENTE
inner join (select codigo_producto,numero, sum(precio * cantidad) from detalle group by codigo_producto) d on f.numero = d.numero;
```

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos de Oracle

adjunto el diagrama logico de la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco desde ya su ayuda.

Comment: podrías añadir la estructura de tus tablas? Mas que nada para ver que campo pertenece a que tablas

Comment: ¿has probado la subconsulta por separado? 
select codigo_producto,numero, sum(precio * cantidad) from detalle group by codigo_producto

probablemente te de error al no añadir todos los campos en el group by

Comment: Ya lo modifique ya agregue el diagrama lógico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado la "estructura" de la consulta simplemente por comodidad.

Así es como lo tienes:

```
SELECT C.CODIGO_CLIENTE, C.NOMBRE, (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) -  
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'YYYY'))) AS EDAD, SUM(PRECIO*CANTIDAD)--Error
FROM CLIENTES C 
INNER JOIN FACTURACION F ON C.CODIGO_CLIENTE = F.CODIGO_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT CODIGO_PRODUCTO,NUMERO, SUM(PRECIO * CANTIDAD) 
            FROM DETALLE GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO) D ON F.NUMERO = D.NUMERO;
```

En la subconsulta deberías darles "alias" a las columnas con `SUM()`.
Como debería quedar la Subconsulta, para que funcione con la consulta que ya tienes:

```
SELECT CODIGO_PRODUCTO,NUMERO, SUM(PRECIO * CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD--Te faltaba el alias
            FROM DETALLE GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO, NUMERO
```

También algo que me parece una buena forma de trabajar, ya que le pones "alias" a las tablas, Clientes = C, Facturación = F.... **Utilízalos**, tanto para evitar posibles errores de campos ambiguos como para comodidad visual a la hora de identificar campos

Comment: Perdona mi comentario anterior, no había entendido bien como aplicar tu respuesta, posterior a eso me dio problema con la agrupación pero no me había fijado que tenia que agruparlo por ambos (codigo_producto, Numero). Gracias por tu ayuda.